How can I test my Intent Extension implementation?
I'm implementing credit card tokenization with Apple Wallet, more precisely the Extension Flow. The problem is that is very hard to be sure the code is working properly during development since a lot of bureaucracy is required to actual testing start.
Both UI and Non-UI extension are implemented using Intent Extension. Is possible to open a Intent Extension from a test app just to test and see it running?
